# Поочередное сокрытие/открытие компонентов.

Tags: html, javascript

Добрый вечер! Есть простая задачка, поочередно скрывать и открывать два div'а. Вот код на js:

```
 function visible_enable()
     {
          var checkElement1=document.getElementsByName("check1");
          if (checkElement1.checked==1)
            {
               document.getElementsByName("div1").style.display = 'none';
               document.getElementsByName("div2").style.display = 'block';
               location.reload();
            }
            else
            {
               document.getElementsByName("div1").style.display = 'block';
               document.getElementsByName("div2").style.display = 'none';           
               location.reload();
            }
          }       
     }
```

А вот два дива и checkbox:

```
<div name="div1">Это первый див</div>
      <div name="div2" style='display:none'>Это второй див</div>
      <input type='checkbox' name='check1' value='' onclick='visible_enable();'>
```

Почему не работает эта фишка? Где ошибка?

Вот ссылка: http://jsfiddle.net/WeXv6/1/

Comment: во-первых не совсем понятно, где происходит вызов функции, а во-вторых - зачем перезагружать страницу?

Comment: вызов функции происходит в событие onClick ческбокса. А с перегрузкой я действительно замудрил наверное. Просто боялся, что не будет работать эта фишка. Я js плохо знаю, делал интуинтивно и по примерам.

Comment: getElementsByName() возвращает массив объектов, а не сам объект. Нужно делать приблизительно так: var div1 = document.getElementsByName("div1"); div1 = div1[0];

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WeXv6/2/
но это всё равно все неправильно.

Comment: А как правильно тогда делать?

Comment: не использовать onclick как минимум

Comment: Для начала в js есть лишний }

getElementsByName отдаёт нам массив элементов, даже если это один элемент, то есть нужно обращаться как к элементу массива checkElement1[0].checked

соответственно document.getElementsByName("div1")[0], но я бы для обычных элементов использовал id и getElementById

Comment: А чем так плох onClick? Насчет лишней } это описался просто. У меня уже везде в проекте используются атрибуты name, а не id потому мне уже поздно переходить на это...

Comment: onclick не так плох, гораздо хуже применение атрибута name в элементе div. У элемента div согласно стандартам html не должно быть такого атрибута, он бывает у элементов форм и служит как ключ в паре ключ-значение при отправке данных из формы на сервер.

Comment: А если говорить о каких-нибудь элементах вроде span или p, то тут тоже атрибут name неуместен? Где можно прочитать об этом, где и когда лучше использовать?

Comment: @IntegralAL, почитать об этом можно здесь http://htmlbook.ru/html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onclick с инпута убираем, меняем name на id в дивах и пишем:

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[name="check1"]'),
    firstDiv = document.getElementById('div1'),
    secondDiv = document.getElementById('div2');

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(){
    if(this.checked){
        firstDiv.style.display = 'none';
        secondDiv.style.display = 'block';
    }else{
        firstDiv.style.display = 'block';
        secondDiv.style.display = 'none';
    }
}, false);
```